# Can we install numpy on windows 7 without internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy

I got some issues while installing numpy it said that
"The current version is not supported for numpy"
But I have installed python 3.7 the new version which was available on their official website 
Please help me with this

Comment: you can install anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ 
which come prebuild with numpy, pandas and many other libraries.

Comment: The question title and question body seem to be asking two different questions. What's up with that?

Comment: This maybe a paradoxical question. By the time OP sees answers here, he must have had internet, which would render the answers useless.

Answer (score 0):

Download required packages from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy, then use pip to install on any offline machine.

```
pip install path/to/numpy.whl
```